# INotifyCollectionChanged UI not updated

Tags: c#, wpf

I have problem with updating UI. I have class which, is used to binding my UI elements:

```
public class engine : INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        RWProject project = new RWProject();

        public ObservableCollection<string> ProjectListBinding
        {
            get {  return project.list(); }
        }

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            {
                this.CollectionChanged(this, eventArgs);
            }
        }

        private ICommand _usunProjekt;
        public ICommand UsunProjekt
        {
            get
            {
                _usunProjekt = new UsunProjektCommand();
                return _usunProjekt;
            }           
        }

        private ICommand _dodajProjekt;
        public ICommand DodajProjekt
        {
            get
            {
                _dodajProjekt = new DodajNowyProjektCommand();
                return _dodajProjekt;
            } 
        }
    }
```

ProjectListBinding is a list of files names inside folder, and this names are displayed on listview control.

Commands DodajProjekt creating in same folder, new file (UsunProjekt - removing)
Commands are binded to buttons.

I need to rise event

```
 OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
```

to update UI after command is executed, but I don't knew where to attach this part of code. Or maybe I should do it in different way ? 
With code I already have, bindings and commands are working fine, only updating not working at all. 
Can You help me solve this ?
Piotr

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you class implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` without also implementing some collection interface, e.g. `ICollection` or `IList`.

Comment: Yes, You are right, but is it possible to force ObservableCollection to refresh and UI olso ?

Comment: ObservableCollection raises the CollectionChanged event when elements are added or removed. Anything else wouldn't make sense. If you need your UI to update when an existing element changes, the element class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`. From your view you need to bind to `ProjectListBinding` which will automatically raise `INotifyCollectionChanged` for you and update the UI. Of course, assuming that the class that you have (i.e. `engine`) is your view model.

When running your command, you should update `ProjectListBinding` for `INotifyCollectionChanged` events to be risen. That is, both your commands `DodajNowyProjektCommand` and `UsunProjekt` should be operating on `ProjectListBinding`.